# ReferenceError when trying to destructure Object.entries() in for-loop

Tags: javascript

I figured out how to make this work, but I cannot for the life of me understand how this can happen!

This throws [ReferenceError: Property ‘date’ doesn’t exist]:

```
for (const [date, items] of Object.entries(object)) { console.log(date) }
```

This works:

```
for (const entries of Object.entries(object)) {
      const date = entries[0]
      const items = entries[1]
      console.log(date)
 }
```

It's the same object, every single time. It only has one entry, This is how it looks when I log it using Object.entries(object):

```
[
   "2022-01-02",
   {
      "a":[objects],
      "b": object,
      "c":[objects]
   }
]
```

If I log *date* in the working code block, I can see *date* being logged. But trying to log *date* when restructured, it throws. So seems like it's throwing because I'm trying to destructure the array. But WHY!? I'm currently on React Native, if that is valuable in any way.

Comment: Side note: the object you're iterating over is called `items` and you're also trying to destructure `items` from it which will probably give you a reference error.

Comment: the error you described it's not the error actually occurring like someone else also pointed out. That's the error thrown `ReferenceError: can't access lexical declaration 'items' before initialization` and it was as easy as doing a live snippet to show it live. And the solution was as easy as changing the name of the `items` variable in the array destructuring

Comment: Thanks for the replies! My apologies for the bad variable namings. I tried to simplify it by renaming the variables. The variable names are not the problem. Fixed the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you're redeclaring the variable `items`.

Try changing the destructured variable name to something else:

```js
const items = {
  '2023-01-02': [
    "value 1"
  ]
}

// works fine
for (const [date, entryItems] of Object.entries(items)) { console.log(date) }

// throws
for (const [date, items] of Object.entries(items)) { console.log(date) }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your object is an array at base, then you cannot destructurate an array with keys, but with indexes

```
let data = [
   "date",
   {
      "a":[objects],
      "b": object,
      "c":[objects]
   }
]
```

Data doesnt have keys but indexes... There is no entry with key `date` or `items`

Comment: OP's example is the entry returned by `Object.entries` (the [key, value]), not the outer data structure.